# Navigating from one UITableView to another inside appDelegate

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, dropbox

The first UITableView is presented inside a Popover that is called from the RootViewController of the application.

I need to navigate to another UITableView inside the same popover. This is easy to do if you just instance an object of the second UITableView and push it from the first one.

In the next paragraph I write as taking for granted some facts, please correct me if I'm wrong.

The problem here is that this process should be done inside the appDelegate. This is because I'm implementing Dropbox API and I need the pushViewController to be done immediately after the login process is done, which means the navigation through UITableViews has to be done inside of the application:handleOpenURL. I asume that application:handleOpenURL has to be called right there and that's why I also asume the pushViewController has to be done there in order to have the navigation done after the Dropbox API validation window is presented, without having to make the user do anything else.

This is how my code looks like:

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>{
  UINavigationController *navigationController;
    NSString *relinkUserId;
  UIWindow *window;
  TableViewControllerForStorageList *rootViewController;
  ViewController *viewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet TableViewControllerForStorageList *rootViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet ViewController *viewController;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
  if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
            [(TableViewControllerForStorageList *)self.window.rootViewController PushView];

        }
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

TableViewControllerForStorageList.h

```
-(void)PushView;
```

TableViewControllerForStorageLost.m

```
-(void)PushView
{
  TableViewControllerIpadStorage *tableViewControllerIpadStorage = [[TableViewControllerIpadStorage alloc]initWithNibName:@"TableViewControllerIpadStorage" bundle:Nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewControllerIpadStorage animated:YES];
}
```

Off course I got sure that Application:HandleOpenURL is running, but when calling PushView from there the error is [ViewController PushView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

So, how can make the navigation be done from there? Which basics about objective c am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear from your question how your app is structured, so this answer may not be the best solution for your problem but hopefully it gives you some idea of how your view controller hierarchy is likely built up from your app delegate.

Lets say your first view controller class is named `FirstViewController`. Either your app delegate has a direct reference to an instance of this view controller, or it can access it through a parent view controller (perhaps via `window.rootViewController`).

Now lets say you have a method in `FirstViewController` named `pushNextViewController` that performs the task of pushing the second table view controller.

You can call that method from within the `application:handleOpenURL:` method of your app delegate.

This might look something like:

```
[self.window.rootViewController.firstViewController pushNextViewController];
```

There are other ways you could get a reference to your instance of `FirstViewController` and it would be cleaner if your `rootViewController` was a custom subclass so your could create a `pushNextViewController` method there and from that method tell your `FirstViewController` instance to `pushNextViewController`:

```
[self.window.rootViewController pushNextViewController];
```

Note that in both examples above, you will need to cast the `rootViewController` to whatever class it is actually an instance of or the compiler will warn you that it does not have the property `firstViewController` (example 1) or the method `pushNextViewController` (example 2).

**EDIT:** If your `rootViewController` is a `UINavigationController`, then your code might look more like:

```
UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)window.rootViewController;
FirstViewController* vc = navController.viewControllers[0];
[vc pushNextViewController];
```

**EDIT 2:** OK, It looks like the confusion here is that the `window` object has a `rootViewController` property (which appears to be pointing to your `navigationController`) and then you also have a `rootViewController` instance variable in your app delegate. These are two different objects, making your naming convention a bit confusing, but if I am right then the following should work:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
            [rootViewController PushView];

        }
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

You should consider changing the name of your app delegate's reference to your `TableViewControllerForStorageList` to something other than `rootViewController` to alleviate some confusion.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the answer that I need, but how would the code look if I follow this instruction: "you will need to cast the rootViewController to whatever class it is actually an instance of" ?

Comment: If you are asking what typecasting looks like in general, you should probably do a bit of reading on Objective-C because there are likely other key language features you are not familiar with as well. As for your particular case, it depends on what class you are typecasting to, but clean code that does the typecast will look similar to my code in my second edit above (I typecast `rootViewController` to `UINavigationController*`). I really do recommend some reading/googling, but if you want more specific help to get you past this then provide some code in your question for me to go off of.

Comment: I saw your second edit. I made another edit deleting the DidFinishedLaunching section of the appDelegate in order to avoid confusions about the pointers. In fact, I deleted that code. With your editing it works better cause no errors are reported, but the PushView method still does not run. I don't really understand why does it work now and why now at least doesn't report errors. Which basics am I missing to understand what I'm doing? Which is a good place to read about those basics?

Comment: It sounds like the interface builder connections are not set up correctly (or at least not in the way I assumed they were set up). If you are uncertain about how the `IBOutlet`s in your code relate to the XIB files in your project, a google search for "ios interface builder tutorial" could help a lot. I recommend being familiar with Apple's [App Design Basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AppDesignBasics/AppDesignBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW1) as well. Unfortunately I am not entirely sure how else to help.

Comment: I'm not really sure if its an interface builder issue. I found out that the rootViewController *TableViewControllerForStorageList instance has a nil value (0X00000000) when I call the PushView method. That might mean its a new instance that is not considering that the TableViewControllerForStorageList has already run before calling the HandleOpenURL. I'm not sure if I'm messing up things with concepts. If you can't help any more right now I'll think more about this so I can ask you better questions and we can get the answer.

Comment: I suspected that `rootViewController` was a nil reference. This either means you have not connected anything in your XIB files to that `IBOutlet` or it means that view controller is never created. Since you are seeing the view controller, you must not have the IB connection set up. I think this conversation is becoming less and less relevant to others. Check my profile for my email and send me your Xcode project if you would like me to see if I can quickly track down the missing link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23175/discussion-between-laureano-bonilla-and-mathew)